# Problems with importing tumble-bar.html into index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to import *tumble-bar.html* into *index.html* using *tumble-bar.js*.

I'm using [GitHub](https://github.com/tumblegamer/Tumble-NetSearch.git), so I cannot use PHP's import.

*index.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <title>Tumblegamer WebSearch</title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE/stylesheets/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE/stylesheets/tumble-bar.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-/*I DONT KNOW WHAT VERSION TO USE*/.js"></script> 
        <script src="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE/javascript/tumble-bar.js"></script>

        <!-- Put the following javascript before the closing </head> tag. -->
        <script>
          (function() {
            var cx = 'I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
          })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <center>
                <header>
                    <div class="tumble"></div><!-- I want to put tumble-bar.html here -->
                </header>
                <main>
                    <img class="Logo" src="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">
                    <gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p><strong>New:</strong><a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">Alpha Test Tumble NetBrowse</a>.</p>
                </main>
                <footer>
                    © 2015 Tumblegamer - <a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">Tumblegamer Home</a> - <a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">About Tumblegamer</a> - Tumble NetSearch Alpha (<a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">about</a>)
                </footer>
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*tumble-bar.html:*

```
<navbar class"TumbleBar">   
    <center>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE" class="active">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">YouTube</a></li>
            <li><a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">Mail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Social &#x25BC;</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">Google+</a></li>
                    <li><a href="I DONT WANT TO ADVERTISE">Twitch</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </center>
</navbar>
```

Can you help me with importing *tumble-bar.html* to `<div class="tumble"></div>` and also tell me the `<script></script>` command of what version of jQuery you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do [`$().load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get that html.

```
$('.tumble').load('tumble-bar.html', function () {/* callback if needed */});
```

You also can find something like [`$(document).load(function () {})`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/). It's different function, because it will execute `function` when document is loaded.

Difference between calls are that in first one you pass string as URL.

About jQuery version:
`1.*` version will support older IE browsers and for that is slower.
`2.*` has thrown old IE support and has some more improvements.

For fresh start use `2.*` version. If you have some old code, use same jQuery as that code.